# Reactjs drawer animation affecting other elements on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

sample image giving a fare idea:

[image: sample image giving a fare idea.]

**I have two main components**

1. first component (**NewsFeed**) default state is *expanded* size (1000px)
2. second component (**Chat**) default state is *collapsed* (200px) where only people avatar with their names are displayed in list.

---

**two Chat child component**

1. **PeopleList** which renders a list of people. Default state is *visible*, size is 200px (making the size of **Chat** Component in its *collapsed* state.)
2. **ChatBox** which renders conversation between the user and her people. Default state is *hidden*, size is 400px.

### scenario

1. clicking on a person name from **Chat** Component will expand it showing the **ChatBox** Component attached to the right of the **PeopleList** where both **Chat** stated changed to *expanded* and **ChatBox** state to *visible* changing the **NewsFeed** Component to its *collapsed* state where its size reduced to accommodate **Chat** Component in its new state (*expanded*).

Thanks.

Comment: can u put code  snippets ? so we figure out your perspective

Comment: sorry to disappoint but i have not written any code yet , because i do not event know where to start..